# API POST Request in Excel Power Query Resulting in (400) Bad Request Error

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm trying to make a POST request to a USASpending.gov API endpoint using Power Query in Excel. I must admit that this is my first exposure to APIs and I have a limited amount of experience with Power Query / M, but I've spent the majority of my weekend reading/watching tutorials and consuming a bunch of posts from people seeking similar help, and have been unable to figure out the issue with my query.

Based on all of the reading I've done, I'm slightly more confident in the M syntax and am left to assume that I just don't understand the syntax that's required for the POST request. [The documentation for the specific API endpoint is linked here](https://github.com/fedspendingtransparency/usaspending-api/blob/master/usaspending_api/api_contracts/contracts/v2/search/spending_by_transaction.md).

This is the "closest" I think I've gotten thanks to all the examples I've found from helpful people on the internet:

```
let
    url = "https://api.usaspending.gov/api/v2/search/spending_by_transaction/",
    
    body = "{ ""filters""{ ""keywords"": [""my_input""], ""award_type_codes"": [""A"", ""B"", ""C"", ""D""]}",
    
    response = Web.Contents(url, [Headers=[#"Content-Type" = "application/json"], Content=Text.ToBinary(body)]),
    responseData = Json.Document(response)
in
    responseData
```

I'm getting a (400) Bad Request error, screenshot below:

[image: (400) Bad Request in Power Query Advanced Editor]

Note that I started from a Blank Query in Excel; if I try to start with "From Web" -> Basic or Advanced options, I get a (405) Method Not Allowed.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?